# jquery clone is not working on droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that i can drag to other div, and its working fine.

But with helper: 'clone', its possible to drag the div, but the droppable its not working.

Do you know how to fix this?

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({ helper: 'clone', revert: 'invalid' });
    $(".droppable").droppable({ 
        accept: ".draggable"
    });
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/p21z4jy0/

Comment: is the droppable having any other jquery-ui widgets (e.g sortable, draggable) if yes they can conflict and interfere, the order in which each widget is added on an existing widget is important (and a known issue in jquery-ui), try adding in different order

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the droppable dont have any other widget!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking http://jsfiddle.net/p21z4jy0/2/

```js
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({ helper: 'clone', revert: 'invalid' });
    $(".droppable").droppable({ 
        accept: function(drag) {
            var dropId = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var dragId = $(drag).attr('data-id');
            return dropId === dragId;
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('.droppable').append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.draggable{
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.droppable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.draggable {
    height:50px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="draggable" data-id='a'>draggable a</div>
<div class="droppable" data-id='a'>droppable a</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with your solution the droppable div is going to up, and not the opposite. And also want to be possible move the draggable div when is in the .droppable content.

Comment: @Oscar this answer solves the problem you asked in question.  if you wanted to keep the original droppable where it is and add a clone to droppable it won't go up, else its a separate issue with your CSS. moving the draggable after drop is also another issue (making the drop work was your issue), all these are already asked and answered. If you do little research on your own you can fix such issues. If you still face such problems afterwards, please post different question. This is a `Q&A` site and coming up with new *requirements* once you get an answer is not encouraged as far as I know...